# Open Helper ormlite Android

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I use ormlite in my android aplication. Firstly I use:

```
OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperClass(nameclass);
//nameclass is my class that create, update database.
//name class is defined as:
private static Class<? extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper> nameclass = OpenHelper.class;
```

I can open my database. The logcat says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6929): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.j256.ormlite.logger.LoggerFactory
```

E/AndroidRuntime( 6929):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager.(OpenHelperManager.java:37)

Thanks a lot

Comment: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.j256.ormlite.logger.LoggerFactory** you forgot about some library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are using the `ormlite-android` but you also need the `ormlite-core` package as well.  See the downloading documentation:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/downloading

To quote:

> For use with Android applications, you should download the ormlite-android-4.41.jar and ormlite-core-4.41.jar files instead. For either JDBC or Android you will also need the ormlite-core release which has the ORMLite backend implementations.

Comment: sir, i get the following exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find support for DatabaseField readOnly` but i have the id field set to `generatedId=true` what could be the issue ?

Comment: Its ok.. the error is solved. i was using ormlite-core 4.48 version and ormlite-android 4.44 and so that was the bug. ormlite-android 4.48 solved the bug

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille - I am using orm and lite-core 4.48 and ormlite-core 4.48, still I see the same error. Any help?

Comment: may be u could try adding the jars the other way round ? Like  by going to buildpath and adding in the external jars . Also try a clean, and restart your eclipse.